# RankX does not work by Categories and only shows '1'

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, rank

### SITUATION

I have a Table with two Columns:

- Category (String)
- Value (Integer)

If I create a measure with **RankX** I get a Rank over the complete table, sorted by value. Everything is fine.

[Table with Category, Value and Rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXjj.png)

RankX_Table Dax:

`RankX_Category = RANKX(all(RankX_Dummy[Category]), [Total_Value]`)

---

### PROBLEM

I want to create a Rank by Category. If I create a measure for this the Rank just shows '1'

[Table with Category, Value, Rank_Table, Rank_Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXjj.png)

| Category | Value | Total_Value | RankX_Table | RankX_Category

| A | 100   | 100   | 3 | 1

| A | 150   | 150   | 1 | 1

| B | 50    | 50    | 9 | 1

| B | 55    | 55    | 8 | 1

| B | 100   | 100   | 3 | 1

etc.

RankX_Category Dax:

```
RankX_Category = RANKX(all(RankX_Dummy[Category]), [Total_Value])
```

I think I miss a detail but I have no Idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
RankX_Category2 = 
 VAR t = CALCULATETABLE(RankX_Dummy, REMOVEFILTERS(RankX_Dummy), VALUES(RankX_Dummy[Category]))
 RETURN
 RANKX(t, [Total_Value] )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx! Will test it later and come back with feedback / upvote.

Comment: Hey David, I am still working on it. My data model is to big for your solution. I receive a error message.

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean when you say your model is too big?

Comment: With the simplified case (here) your solution worked well. I my real dataset i received the error message (I cannot reproduce, because I found a work around). Sorry. 

I will mark yous solution as "solved"

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
RANKX(
    FILTER(ALL(RankX_Dummy[Category]), RankX_Dummy[Category] = EARLIER(RankX_Dummy[Category])),
    RankX_Dummy[Value],
    ,DESC,
    Dense
)
```

Explanation of the DAX query:

**RANKX:** This function calculates the rank based on the specified expression and order. It assigns a rank to each row based on the ordering of the expression.

**FILTER(ALL(RankX_Dummy[Category]), RankX_Dummy[Category] = EARLIER(RankX_Dummy[Category])):** This part of the formula filters the table to include only the rows with the same `Category` as the current row. `EARLIER` is used to get the current row's Category value in the iteration context.

**RankX_Dummy[Value]:** This is the expression that will be used for ranking. In this case, it's the `Value` column.

**DESC:** This indicates that the ranking should be in descending order, so the highest values get a lower rank (e.g., 1 for the highest, 2 for the second highest, and so on).

**Dense:** This is an optional parameter that specifies how to handle duplicate values. Dense will assign consecutive ranks to duplicate values, whereas Skip will leave gaps in the ranking for duplicate values.

Comment: Thanx! Great work with extra explanation. Will give it a Try later and come back with feedback / upvote.

Comment: Just tried it and I get the error message "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist"